# ASP.NET Core 3 - nullable type - removes property from json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nullable-reference-types

I have the following class definition

```
#nullable enable
namespace Test
{
    public class MyDetails
    {
        public string? SomeName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

example usage

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetDetails()
{
    return Ok(new MyDetails());
}
```

which generates the following json:

```
{}
```

instead of

```
{
   "someName" : null
}
```

why the null value makes the property to be removed from the output's json?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options => {
     options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = false;
});
```